# How to inject $rootScope into a service?

Tags: angularjs

how to inject a `$rootScope` into the factory definition for the following code (so the file can be minified):

```
(function() {
    var signalRService = function($rootScope) {
       // ... 
    };

    var app = angular.module("App");
    app.factory("signalRService", signalRService);
}());
```

Comment: excuseme, you try to use signalR with angular?

Comment: Yes, is it a bad practice?

Comment: i don't know, just ask you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to go about this is by supplying service definition as an array:

```
var signalRService = ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
   // ... 
}];
```

Argument will be minifed, but the injector will be based off the string in the array.

That said I'd suggest to revise whether this is really the way to go, as generally speaking relying on `$rootScope` is inadvisable, and so is using any kind of scopes directly in services/factories.

Comment: i have a problem with this [example](https://dzone.com/articles/better-way-using-aspnet)